# RaphaelJS library to find intersections of paths

Tags: javascript, graphics, svg, raphael

I'd like to draw shapes which are intersections of circles using [RaphaëlJS](http://raphaeljs.com/). Is there a library out there to do that already? A more general SVG path library would probably work too, but my google foo is failing me.

I'd like to draw shapes like these:

[image: shapes]

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to do this programmatically?  Obviously, programs like inkscape have this ability and can export the product.

Comment: I was playing with a simple 2d game with a destructible landscape, so I wanted to cut bits out of it depending on the player's actions. Since I could get away with a solid background colour, I cheated and just drew my shapes in a solid colour over the landscape.

Comment: Gotcha. Makes perfect sense.  Cursory searches for polygon subtraction brought me to this, though there is no JS implementation - http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~toby/alan/software/

Comment: General Polygon Clipper library (linked in the above comment) has an ActionScript 3.0 port. If you're desperate, it shouldn't be _too_ hard to port that over to JavaScript, given they're both ECMAScript dialects.

Comment: [Canvas](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas_sheet/HTML5_Canvas_Cheat_Sheet.png) does this out of the box if you are not set in stone on svg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SVG Compositing](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGCompositing/#comp-op-property) spec describes compositing operations (comp-op property), but they're not currently supported by any browser.

Here's an [example](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGCompositing/examples/compop-porterduff-examples.svg) you can try, but as of writing this it doesn't work in Chrome or Firefox. [Clipping](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SVG_Essentials/Clipping_and_Masking) can work in some cases, but it doesn't allow to do the knock out effect.

On the other hand, [canvas compositing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing) operations are fully supported, so you can try using canvas for your game.